# How to add country flags icon in front of ion-select-option?

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 plus Angular app, in that i'm using ion-select dropdown for country.now i want to add country flags icons in front of country name.below code shows what i'm try.

```html
<ion-select class="dropdownselection" placeholder="PROVINCIA" interface="popover">
                  <ion-select-option value="A Coruña">
                    <ion-icon src="/assets/icons/man.svg"></ion-icon> A Coruña
                  </ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="Álava">Álava</ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="Albacete">Albacete</ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="red">D</ion-select-option>
                </ion-select>
```

[image: i want flag icon before country name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know in Ionic 3 there wasn't a a reliable way to add icons. I'm not sure about Ionic 4, but I use [this plugin](https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable) and its great.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-item-end-template).

Another huge benefit of this plugin is you can search tons of data asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Old, but if someone's needing, you can use country flag emoji's unicode (you can find a list [here](https://emojipedia.org/)).

Make sure you're using UTF-8 as meta charset.

Then, copy/paste the emoji in, by example, an object (between quotes) :
[image]

Finally, use the property in your template `{{ myObject.flagIcon }}`.

Example from my app :

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72858277/how-to-add-flag-icon-beside-ion-select-option

please have a look at the URL once.
Can you please me in this?
@Adrien SAULNIER